# Laravel query wrong format of value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, php-8.1

I'm currently develop a web application with Laravel.
My database engine is a Microsoft SQL Server.

For some data I preferred to generate an uuid.
When I use Windows to run my Laravel app, the uuid format is correct :

- A5EE121A-1F10-46FC-B779-49D2A0FA3B68

But when I ran my Laravel app under linux, and use the same database, the uuid format is like this :

- b"\x1A\x12î¥\x10\x1FüF·yIÒ ú;h"

I don't know where is the problem...
Have you an idea ?

Thanks.

The goal is to retrieve the same format when the Laravel app ran under Windows and under Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `config/database.php` add this

```
'options' => [
PDO::DBLIB_ATTR_STRINGIFY_UNIQUEIDENTIFIER => true,
],
```

[image]
then optimize:clear your app

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Server, UUIDs are typically stored using the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER datatype, which is a 16-byte binary value. When you fetch this value from the database, the driver might represent this binary data differently based on the platform.

- On Windows, when you fetch the UUID from the database, the database driver is likely converting it to its string representation (smth like A5EE121A-1F10-46FC-B779-49D2A0FA3B68).
- On Linux, the database driver might be fetching the raw binary data without converting it to its string representation. As a result, you're seeing the raw bytes (example: b"\x1A\x12î¥\x10\x1FüF·yIÒ ú;h").

To resolve this and retrieve the UUID in a consistent format across both platforms, you can explicitly convert the UUID to its string representation when querying the database.

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(36), [YourUUIDColumn]) AS uuid_string FROM [YourTableName]
```

In your Laravel model, you can use accessors to handle the UUID conversion:

```
public function getUuidAttribute($value)
{
    return strtoupper(bin2hex($value));
}
```

so you can access it in Laravel using `$model->uuid` and get the expected string format.